# Batch File Crashes From Goto Command

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I was making my own little batch file.

It will say Bad Command then goto the typing prompt again but everything I type the wrong command (if) I made cmd my batch shuts off

**Code:**

```
:ccc
set /p cmd=C:\
if %cmd%==edit goto edit
if %cmd%==Edit goto edit
if %cmd%==exit goto exit
if %cmd%==Exit goto exit
if %cmd%==Restart goto restart
if %cnd%==restart goto restart
echo Bad Command
goto ccc
```

Comment: There is a spelling mistake on last `if` line. Put the terms in quotes (or any character) `if "%cmd%"=="edit" goto edit` to have something on both sides to compare. `If /I` does case insensitive comparisons, see `if /?`. PS: Try `set /p cmd=%CD%^>` for a more natural look. See `set /?`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should adding quotes and take a look at this : **[If /I](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html)**  case Insensitive string comparison

```
@echo off
:ccc
set /p "cmd=C:\ "
if /I "%cmd%"=="edit" goto edit
if /I "%cmd%"=="exit" goto exit
if /I "%cmd%"=="restart" goto restart
echo Bad Command
goto ccc
```

Comment: Thanks! Its Fixed.